# Get single value of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am really confused here. I have the result string

```
{ "member_id":"5", "msg":"login successful", "type_id":"1" }
```

and I want to get a single value like

```
 alert(member_id);
 alert(msg);
 alert(type_id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i have result string { "member_id":"5", "msg":"login successful", "type_id":"1" }

1. Convert it to a `JSON` object with `JSON.parse`
2. Access members with either `.` or `[]` notation

```js
var objStr = '{ "member_id":"5", "msg":"login successful", "type_id":"1" }';

var obj = JSON.parse(objStr);


document.write(obj.member_id);

document.write(obj['member_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { "member_id":"5", "msg":"login successful", "type_id":"1" }
console.log(obj.member_id)
```

Comment: It's a string, not a parsed object.